# Show/hide input after click in checkbox

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to Show/hide my input after check/uncheck a checkbox but I getting this info from DB so, I'm using PHP to add 'checked' attribute to my input.

jQuery code is working, but when I refresh the page, my input doesn't show even with attribute checked "enabled".

PHP code

```
  <label>Send cash?</label>
  <input class="reg_cash" type="checkbox" name="reg_cash" value="1" 
  <?php echo ($configs->reg_cash) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>


  <div class="reg_cash_amount">     
    <label>Amount of cash</label>
       <input type="text" name="reg_cash_amount" id="coupon_field"/>
   </div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qmmg3qwo/

Comment: Well, how should `$configs->reg_cash` resolve to true on the server side if you never transmit the fact that it has been checked from client to server?

Comment: @arkascha I can resolve if is checked/unchecked. It's working. But I want to hide/unhide my input with amount value. Checked: show, if not, hide. But, when PHP return "checked" my input still hide.

Comment: OK, no idea how that works, but anyway. The next issue is that you test the `clicked` property only inside the handler of the `click` event. That handler only is executed when the checkbox raises a click event. So there is nothing that is actually checking the checked property upon a reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to hide/show the input field based on database values.

php code

```
<label>Send cash?</label>
  <input class="reg_cash" type="checkbox" name="reg_cash" value="1" 
  <?php echo ($configs->reg_cash) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>

<?php if($configs->reg_cash) { ?>
  <div class="reg_cash_amount">     
    <label>Amount of cash</label>
       <input type="text" name="reg_cash_amount" id="coupon_field"/>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Jquery code

```
$(".reg_cash").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(".reg_cash_amount").show();
    } else {
        $(".reg_cash_amount").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you buddy! This is enough.

Comment: With pleasure. Happy to help you.